# UML Diagram in WinForms

Tags: c#

[image: UML Diagram Image]

Hi, I have added a UML Diagram Image above and I was wondering if what I'm doing is correct? I am currently doing a UML Diagram for "Login : Form" I am using WinForms in visual studio and I was wondering if I am missing out on anything or what should I improve on?

Comment: Add an exclamation point `!` before the link in the post to embed an image. For example the above should be `![UML Diagram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq4Bh.png)`

Comment: I can't do that yet, I need 10 reputations at least.

Comment: => I upvoted so you get the rep.

Comment: Thanks man! Much Appreciated!

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with my UML Diagram?

Answer (score 0):

As UML goes the example looks reasonable.

But there are some things I would consider:

- There are a bunch of button-handlers, but nothing to accept text-input for login name etc?
- Do the login-dialog need buttons like About/Home/userUpdate etc? Most login dialogs is simply username/password text fields and OK/cancel buttons. Possibly with register/recover password links.
- Is UML the best tool for describing UI dialogs? I imaging a simple drawing of the dialog could be more useful when discussing the functionality with colleagues and other stakeholders.

Keep in mind that UML diagrams is one of many tools in development. As with all tools there is some skill involved to know when and how to use it.